# Which package to install to use C/C++ compiler with Eclipse

Tags: software-installation, c++, c, eclipse-cdt

I want to develop C/C++ applications using Eclipse: should I install using

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

Comment: install both I'd say.

Comment: Ubuntu being Linux, `gcc` seems to be available by default.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how which applications you use, the `gcc` package contains the gcc, where the `buil-essential` package contains some additional dev-tools (e.g. `make` and `g++`).
A list of packages included in `build-essential` package can be found [here](http://packages.debian.org/en/sid/build-essential).